# jquery sortable: How to sync 2 sortable lists?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 2 sortable lists which are working separately. I want to sync the 2 lists-- when one list item is moved, the position of related item in another list will also move.
Would you recommend a function or method for me to learn?

Answer (score 2):

This is a **really bad** hack, but it may give you a few ideas to start out on:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/q6bbF/1/)**

```
 $(function () {
     $('#sortable').sortable({
         update: function (event, ui) {
             var x1 = $('#X1').position().top +140,
                 x2 = $('#X2').position().top +140,
                 x3 = $('#X3').position().top +140;
             $('#sortable2 li').css({
                 position:'absolute',
                 width:  $('#sortable li').width()
             });
             $('#Y1').animate({
                 'top': x1
             });
             $('#Y2').animate({
                 'top': x2
             });
             $('#Y3').animate({
                 'top': x3
             });
         }
     });

     $("#sortable").disableSelection();
 });
```

I say this is a really bad hack because it obviously wont scale very well...

You'll probably need to use an [update function](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) and likely some kind of [animation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Another option would be to just copy the html:

**[Working Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/q6bbF/2/)**

```
 $(function () {
     $("#sortable").sortable({
         update: function (event, ui) {
             $('#sortable2').html($('#sortable').html());
         }
     });
     $("#sortable").disableSelection();
 });
```

This will scale a lot better, but it's not as pretty.

Comment: Thanks! I prefer less hackish :-) I think I will work on option two. The thing is that the content of my 2 sortables are slightly different, so, I will use something else instead of html().

Comment: I know this is pretty old now, I was just wondering how you managed to get it working without the use of html() as I also need to do this. The html of my two lists are completely different I need connect them through the use of ID's which are similar ie list1_0 and list2_0 would be connected.

Comment: @Doug feel free to ask a new question and send me the link. I'll have to take a look at what you have so far and your usage context.